# Getting a dict of all the blocks in a Jinja2 template

Tags: python, jinja2

Let's say I have some Jinja2 template with several blocks in it:

```
{% block A %}Blah{% endblock %}
{% block B %}whatever{% endblock %}
{% block C %}you get the idea{% endblock %}
```

I want a Python function that will turn it into a dict (or JSON, or whatever), with one entry for each block. So the output would be something like this:

```
{'A': 'Blah', 'B': 'whatever', 'C': 'you get the idea'}
```

Is there an established way of doing this?

I'm asking because I want to have my application update pages via AJAX rather than reloads while retaining backwards compatibility. If I can parse the blocks of my Jinja2 templates, then I can use the exact same template files to easily generate whole pages or partial pages. So, as an ancillary question... is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check out `Template.blocks` field. It has dict of block render functions.

The block render function returns generator when it's called with context(i guess) as argument.

I hope the following code snippet would help you.

```
    for key, blockfun in template.blocks.iteritems():
        print key, ':',  ''.join(blockfun({}))
```

And the result is:

```
    A : Blah
    C : you get the idea
    B : whatever
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
from jinja2 import Template
from jinja2.utils import concat

t = """{% block A %}Blah{% endblock %}
{% block B %}whatever {{ a }}{% endblock %}
{% block C %}you get the idea{% endblock %}
"""

template = Template(t)
context = template.new_context({'a': 'AAAAAAAA'})
A = concat(template.blocks['A'](context))
B = concat(template.blocks['B'](context))
C = concat(template.blocks['C'](context))

print A
print B
print C
```

That gives me each of the three blocks, rendered, in three separate variables.